# Можно сделать поле ToggleLine = NULL в зависимости от значения поля IdGeometryType?(SQL) Сделать дефолтное значение с условием

Tags: sql, sqlite, if

У меня есть таблица PanoramaObj:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно автоматически делать поле ToggleLine = NULL, если IdGeometryType != 0?
если равен IdGeometryType == 0;  ставить дефолтное значение false.

Тип ToggleLine - Bool, который может быть NULL

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В дефолтные значение не добавляются SQL запросы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно триггер сделать.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov можно назначить полю дефолтное значение с условием ? Триггер может быть в двух состояниях ...я не совсем понимаю что предлагаете . Мне надо чтоб поле в определённых случаях не существовало ещё

Comment: Триггер - это не тип поля, а процедура, которая выполняется при вставке/изменении данных.

Comment: @Akina пример или ссылку ? я не слышал о таком

Comment: [Trigger](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)

Comment: [Generated Columns](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/gencol.html) - для справки, тоже может пригодиться

Comment: В чём вообще смысл этого поля ToggleLine? Если оно напрямую зависит от другой колонки? Значит его можно смело выкинуть. А значение вычислять на клиенте по полю IdGeomertyType.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Смысл поля от сортировать обрабатываются не обрабатывается линейный объект ... мне надо ещё запоминать в БД что настроил пользователь

Comment: @Alexander Petrov А сделать поля NULL, потому что у площадных, точеных , векторных объектов оно не нужно... Если есть предложения как сделать оптимальней очень рад буду выслушать . Буду благодарен и +1 один в карму, ещё бы , если бы стаяло в профиле угостить чашкой кофе , перевел бы денежку ... видел как не которые на англоязычном форуме так собирают донаты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В тегах к вопросу отмечена СУБД sqlite. По этому я могу предложить решение этой задачи в рамках возможности именно этой СУБД. Но с учетом, что эта СУБД не является строго типизированной СУБД, то значения false и NULL как таковые для неё ничего не значат. По этому что бы выполнить ваше условие вопроса они взяты в кавычки, что сама sqlite интерпретирует как строковые константы. И так, сначала создаем таблицу и нужный триггер:

```
CREATE
    TABLE PanoramaObj (
        idGeometryType INTEGER,
        ToggleLine BOOLEAN DEFAULT "false"
);

CREATE TRIGGER ToggleLine_Change
AFTER INSERT ON PanoramaObj FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE PanoramaObj SET ToggleLine = "NULL" WHERE idGeometryType != 0;
END;
```

Затем наполняем таблицу тестовыми кортежами:

```
INSERT INTO PanoramaObj (idGeometryType) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO PanoramaObj (idGeometryType) VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO PanoramaObj (idGeometryType) VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO PanoramaObj (idGeometryType, ToggleLine) VALUES (0, "true");
```

В результате получаем таки записи:

```
SELECT * FROM PanoramaObj;

idGeometryType|ToggleLine
1|NULL
0|false
5|NULL
0|true
```

При этом этот триггер, как видно из выборки не мешает задавать и true в записях, если не выполняется условие `!=0`

P.S: вашу огромную таблицу пришлось для примера сократить :)

P.P.S: И если делать выборку уже из существующей базы с неправильно расставленным полем TogleLine, то можно это делать через представление примерно вот так:

```
CREATE VIEW PanoramaObj_view AS
    SELECT
        idGeometryType,
        CASE WHEN idGeometryType != 0 THEN "NULL" ELSE "true" END
            AS ToggleLIne
    FROM PanoramaObj;
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно за потраченное время и труд... Но не совсем то что я хотел ... У меня таблица уже создана ... в вопросе опубликовал картинку(в вопросе она последняя) , куда мне надо добавить условие для дефолтного значения ToggleLine. Мне надо чтоб автоматически , если я даже не указываю поля ToggleLine относительно колонки IdGeometryType выставлялось значение колонки ToggleLine

Comment: хотя в ответе есть TRIGGER можно по аналоги добавить попробовать

Comment: Для действий во время выборки, по идее, можно создать не триггер, а вьюшку.

Comment: У меня почему то в дефолтное значение вообще нельзя добавить не какие команды SQL

Comment: Тогда можно вот так: CREATE VIEW test AS SELECT idGeometryType, CASE WHEN idGeometryType != 0 THEN "NULL" ELSE "true" END AS ToggleLIne FROM PanoramaObj; А уже после этого можно нормальную выборку делать из вьюшки test

Comment: Я опубликовал в вопросе что выдаёт когда я пытаюсь добавить код в дефолтное значение. Я так понимаю это надо добавлять когда ,добавляем запись ? ... Но у меня уже таблица сформирована , она будет только обновляться ...хотя надо попробовать в UPDATE поставить

Comment: Да, триггер можно на update повесить, но в качестве default-значения такое повесить в sqlite вроде не получиться. Самый нормальный вариант, это тригер, на обновление и вставку, что бы поле правильно заполнялось уже существующей программой, и обращение к таблице черезь view, если пишутся новые запросы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111082/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and--).